# Why do compounds with similar properties have different Stitch IDs?

Tags: drugs, cheminformatics

I'm not from the Pharmacy or Chemistry background. I have been wondering why certain drug compounds have similar properties but each of them have different Stitch IDs in PubChem?

For example:

- Stitch ID 9782 [Betamethasone](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/9782)
- Stitch ID 5743 [Dexamethasone](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/5743)

Answer (score 4):

Bethamethasone and dexamethasone are different chemicals, hence they behave different, therefore they have different identification numbers. The numbers you cite are not STITCH IDs, and as far as my research goes these do not exist. Instead they are [CID - PubChem Compound Identification](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/search/help_search.html#Cid) numbers.

[image: dexamethasone] [image: Betamethasone]

As you can see the molecules are diastereomers. The stereo centre of the [steroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steroid) differs at carbon-16. When you look them up with [STICH 4.0](http://stitch.embl.de/) you will see differences with their predicted functional partners. While the first one is nearly identical, the second partner for [betamethasone](http://stitch.embl.de/cgi/show_network_section.pl?all_channels_on=1&interactive=yes&network_flavor=confidence&targetmode=proteins&identifier=-9782&species=9606) is proopiomelanocortin, while for [dexamethasone](http://stitch.embl.de/cgi/show_network_section.pl?all_channels_on=1&interactive=yes&network_flavor=confidence&targetmode=proteins&identifier=-5743&species=9606) it is ABCG2.

For more information on STITCH (‘search tool for interactions of chemicals’) I recommend: [Michael Kuhn, Christian von Mering, Monica Campillos, Lars Juhl Jensen, and Peer Bork, *Nucl. Acids Res.* **2008**, *36* (Database issue): D684–D688.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1093%2Fnar%2Fgkm795) (Open Access); PMCID: [PMC2238848](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2238848/).

Image sources:

- National Center for Biotechnology Information. PubChem Compound Database; CID=9782, https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/9782 (accessed Apr. 20, 2016).
- National Center for Biotechnology Information. PubChem Compound Database; CID=5743, https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/5743 (accessed Apr. 20, 2016).